# How to find the intersection of list of intervals?

Tags: python, intersection

I have list of intervals like this:

```
[[-5, 10], [-3, 5], [-53.7228, 3.72281], [-3, 4], [-6.32456, 6.32456]]
```

and i need to find intersection of all these intervals

answer is

```
[-3,3.72281]
```

Maybe someone knows how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried something ? I guess you would solve this the same way you solve a linear equation system with a pencil on a paper..

Comment: Do you know how to do this on paper (not with programming)? If not, then this is not a programming question, it's a mathematical question which is not appropriate for this site. This is a site to get objective answers to objective questions about code itself; design and code are completely different things. You should post here when having trouble _implementing_ a design _in code_; we're not here to help with the design _itself_.

Comment: That's not how "intersection" works according to my understanding of the term.  What are these segments of?

Comment: explain your segments.   I just slope and slope intersect and didn't get your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this trivial example, you seem to want the maximum of the first value and minimum of the second value.

```py
l = [[-5, 10], [-3, 5], [-53.7228, 3.72281], [-3, 4], [-6.32456, 6.32456]]

v1 = max([pair[0] for pair in l])  # -3
v2 = min([pair[1] for pair in l])  # 3.72281

assert v1 < v2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help, this is exactly what i need:)

Comment: For edge case ```l = [[-5,10], [10, 30]]``` add ```<=``` because intersection of one point is a valid solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I won't solve the problem for you, however idea is simple:

Take first element of your list as a result. Then iterate from the second position in the list till the end and reassign your result to intersection of result and current element.

what you have at the end is your intersection